# How can we use induction on 'i' here to form first to second equation?

Tags: induction, solution-verification

This is for a multi-class M/M/1/∞/PR queue. The equations in the talk are 3.40 and 3.41 where it is given:

$$\sigma_i \equiv\sum_{k=1}^i \rho_k,i=1,2,\cdots,r $$

[image: solution to equation]

Comment: Induction is used for proving the the formula, not coming up with it. Are you asking how to prove it using induction, given the formula?

Comment: Yes exactly as the given parameters are....let me add those in question. The induction we learned was just in proving the formulas for k and k+1 vaules but it doesnt satisfy here for the r.

Comment: removed the image. fix the rest

Comment: Is the image not workable... I could not find the formula bar to write it...